# Change content dependent on value

Tags: angular

I'm working with Angular 4 and I have a problem with conditional style changing. I have a table and values in it. I need the values in a column to be changed depending if the value connected or disconnected. For example - if the value is connected, then it will display ON. If the value is disconnected it will display OFF

There is fragment of my code below, but it doesn't work like I'd like to:

```
<ion-note *ngIf="selectedLaptop?.state.label" item-end>
            {{ selectedLaptop?.state.label }}
          </ion-note>
```

if the state.label ="connected" in the database I want to display ON
Else I want to display OFF

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is your output?

Comment: My output is working well, i just want to change in the front if it's on the database connected i want to display ON or an green cercle, else if it's disconnected i want to display OFF or a red cercle .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should use an icon library. I can't tell you which one, it's up to you.

After that, you can then use the value of the label to put a condition on which icon will be displayed.

```
<ion-note *ngIf="selectedLaptop?.state.label" item-end>
  <icon>{{ selectedLaptop.state.label === 'ON' ? 'checkmark' : 'forbidden' }}</icon>
</ion-note>
```

N.B. : you can also do this with images

```
<ion-note *ngIf="selectedLaptop?.state.label" item-end>
  <img [src]="selectedLaptop.state.label === 'ON' ? 'checkmark.jpg' : 'forbidden.jpg'">
</ion-note>
```